What metric to use for this dark matter simulation?
I am reading this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.08064 which uses the GR version of euler equations in fluid dynamic to simulate the evolution of a perfect fluid system. (PDF)
and this is the paper which derived the equations they use
Monaghan J. J., Price D. J., 2001, Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society, 328, 381
My problem in recreating this code is the choice of metric. They are assuming a perfect fluid model and they also mention they're using " fixed background metrics (Minkowski, Schwarzschild and
Kerr in Cartesian Boyer-Lindquist coordinates)"
What does background metric mean?
I want to simulate spherically symmetric non rotating system, so I think that means using the Schwarzschild metric. But isn't that a vacuum solution? I need to know the metric at the position of my individual particles to be able to time evolve them, which means in the bulk of my system, not in vacuum.
pages 1,2,3,8,9, are more relevant to my purposes.

Usually people care about relativistic effects in the strong gravity regime (i.e. near black holes). This is particularly the case for fluid dynamics, as the main motivator is accretion discs and related phenomena (like tidal disruptions near super-massive black holes). In these regimes, one can separate out the self-gravitation of the fluid with the strong gravity "source" (i.e. the black hole), since the effect of the fluid on the source will be negligible.
So simply put, if you are solving things in the context of an accretion disk/orbital dynamics you should use the Schwartzchild/Kerr background metric (with suitable choices for mass/angular momentum). If you are interest in relativistic effects of some fluid flow where there is no "source" term you should use the Minkowski.

I see. But the simulation i am thinking of has no strong source term. It is only a spherical halo of matter which evolves merely by mutual interaction of particles themselves. That is also what the paper considers.

That wouldnt even be a "fixed" metric then right?

I'm fairly certain in this work they are only considering Newtonian gravity for the self-interactions; the metric is fixed to one of Minkowski, Kerr, or Schwartzchild. Trying to fully solve for the metric evolution including particles would be very computationally demanding. This is what numerical relativity simulations do, and it is expensive even for two black holes.

They mention in the abstract: "the method lays the foundation for future
direct coupling with numerical relativity" i.e. they haven't done it yet since they know it is hard ;)

Thank you, it makes sense. Appreciate it
